# What are the major differences between the anime/manga and the live action version of Perfect Girl Evolution?

Tags: the-wallflower

I really loved the live-action version of *Yamato Nadeshiko Shichi na Henge!* (or, *Perfect Girl Evolution!* / *The Wallflower*) and I'm considering picking up the manga or anime because of how much I liked it. However, I'm curious: **what are the major changes that the live-action made?**

I know one of these changes is aging up the characters; the cast is about college-aged in the live-action, but they're in high school (they attend a *gakuen*) in the manga. I also know that the landlady's son is a live-action only character. Are there other big differences between the two?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%83%88%E3%83%8A%E3%83%87%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B3%E4%B8%83%E5%A4%89%E5%8C%96_(%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB)), the main differences are:

> - Kyouhei becomes the main character. Sunako is listed as the 3rd cast in the credit.
> - Kyouhei, Takenaga, Yukinojou, Ranmaru, and Noi are high school students in the original work, but they are undergraduate students in the TV drama.
> - Mine (Sunako's aunt; the landlady) doesn't have children in the original work. However, in the TV drama, Takeru is introduced as an original character playing the role of her son. He self-proclaims to be the keeper of the mansion while she is away.
> - Shinichi, the master of the coffee shop (*Meykuu Iri*, "Unsolved") that Kyouhei and his friends like to go, appears as a regular cast in the TV drama.
> - Compared to the original work, Sunako's personality is sharply changed. Even with the usually timid and negative personality, when Kyouhei calls her *Busunako* (Extremely ugly Sunako, from *busu* + *Sunako*), she will display her paranormal-thingy and high fighting power and also her personality becomes stronger.